# Is it possible to make reusable form components with ngMessages?

Tags: angularjs, components, directive, ng-messages

Here is the html code, which i want to make a directive

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-success':signupForm.username.$touched && signupForm.username.$valid,'has-error':signupForm.username.$touched && signupForm.username.$invalid,'has-feedback':signupForm.username.$touched }">
    <input tabindex="1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" ng-model="authCtrl.user.username" required ng-minlength='5' ng-maxlength='10' name="username" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9]*$/">
    <span class="glyphicon" ng-show="signupForm.username.$touched" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback':signupForm.username.$touched && signupForm.username.$valid,'glyphicon-remove':signupForm.username.$touched && signupForm.username.$invalid,'form-control-feedback':signupForm.username.$touched}"></span>
    <div ng-messages="signupForm.username.$error" ng-show="signupForm.username.$touched">
        <div ng-messages-include="/static/app/components/widget/widget.view.input-error.html"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I couldn't figure out, how to pass the variable for any component i.e. formname.inputname.$error

**Update : Progress so far:**

template :

```
    <widget-form-input
  input-type='authCtrl.input.username.type'
  input-placeholder='authCtrl.input.username.placeholder'
  input-name='authCtrl.input.username.name'
  input-model='authCtrl.user.username'></widget-form-input>
```

directive :

```
    function widgetFormInput(){
        var input = {};
        input.restrict = 'E';
        input.scope = {
            'inputType' : '=',
            'inputPlaceholder' : '=',
            'inputName' : '=',
            'inputModel' : '=',
            'inputMaxlength' : '=?',
            'inputMinlength' : '=?',
            'inputPattern' : '=?',
        }
        input.templateUrl = '/static/app/components/widget/widget.view.form-input.html';
        return input;
    }
```

directive template :

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-success':signupForm.inputName.$touched && signupForm.inputName.$valid,'has-error':signupForm.inputName.$touched && signupForm.inputName.$invalid,'has-feedback':signupForm.inputName.$touched }">
<input tabindex="1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{inputPlaceholder}}" ng-model="inputModel" required ng-minlength='inputMinlength' ng-maxlength='inputMaxlength' name="{{inputName}}" ng-pattern="inputPattern">
<span class="glyphicon" ng-show="signupForm.inputName.$touched" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback':signupForm.inputName.$touched && signupForm.inputName.$valid,'glyphicon-remove':signupForm.inputName.$touched && signupForm.inputName.$invalid,'form-control-feedback':signupForm.inputName.$touched}"></span>
<div ng-messages="signupForm.inputName.$error" ng-show="signupForm.inputName.$touched">
    <div ng-messages-include="/static/app/components/widget/widget.view.input-error.html"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-messages is already a directive.

Comment: I know that, what i want is to make an directive which will have input with validation, so that i can reuse it.

Comment: udpated in question.

Comment: can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing the inputname as inputName. This is fine. You need to pass the form name too. But you are creating isolate scope. Pass the form name as well, like so:

```
<widget-form-input
  input-type='authCtrl.input.username.type'
  input-placeholder='authCtrl.input.username.placeholder'
  input-name='authCtrl.input.username.name'
  input-model='authCtrl.user.username'
  form-name='signupForm'></widget-form-input>
```

Update the directive scope like so:

```
 input.scope = {
            'inputType' : '=',
            'inputPlaceholder' : '=',
            'inputName' : '=',
            'inputModel' : '=',
            'inputMaxlength' : '=?',
            'inputMinlength' : '=?',
            'inputPattern' : '=?',
            'formName' : '@' //This will be treated as a string
        }
```

Finally, update your directive template like so:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-success':formName.inputName.$touched && formName.inputName.$valid,'has-error':formName.inputName.$touched && formName.inputName.$invalid,'has-feedback':formName.inputName.$touched }">
```

You will need to update the hardcoded form name everywhere in the directive template to point to the formName variable.